# Ismorphism between $Aff(\mathbb{R})/T(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ where $Aff(\mathbb{R})= \{ ax +b\}$ and $T(\mathbb{R})=\{x +b \}$

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, normal-subgroups

> Let $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ be a set of bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $$f_{a,b}(x) = ax + b$$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.
>   Let now $\text{T} (\mathbb{R})$ be the set of functions of the form $f(x) = x+ b$. Show that $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ is a group and that $\text{T}(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal sub-group of $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$.

I had no issues doing this. To show that $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ is a group, I simply showed that it is a sub-group of bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself with the composition law. To show that $\text{T}(\mathbb{R})$ is normal didn't either give much difficulties.

Now, I am asked to do this:

> Show that there exists and isomorphism between $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})/ \text{T}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$.

And here I struggle to give any answer. I am sure I have to construct the function. To do so, I would need to understand how do the elements of $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})/ \text{R}(\mathbb{R})$ look exactly. But I don't see what they look like. And then, I have no idea how to go on to construct an isomorphism!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{R})/ \mathrm{T}(\mathbb{R})$
are equivalence classes $[f]$ of affine maps $f : x \mapsto ax+b$.

The equivalence relation is given as follows. We have $f \sim g$ if and only if there is some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that
$f = g \circ t_{\lambda}$, where $t_{\lambda} : x \mapsto x + \lambda$.
In other words, any affine map $g$ is identified with its translates $x \mapsto g(x+\lambda)$.

In particular, an affine map $x \mapsto ax+b$ is identified with its translate $x \mapsto ax+b-b = ax$, so that any affine map is equivalent to a homotethy. This leads to the following guess:

> The function $\phi : \Bbb R^{\times} \to \mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{R})/ \mathrm{T}(\mathbb{R})$  given by $$\phi(a) = h_a : x \mapsto ax$$
>   is a group isomorphism.

The argument I provided above shows that $\phi$ is surjective. I let you check that it is indeed a morphism, and that it is injective.